# Separate the timestamps from the actual table in a Database

Tags: database-design, timestamp, separation-of-concerns

I was wondering if it was good practice to create a separate `table` juste for the `timestamp` in a database.

I have a database that has multiple tables that uses timestamps - all the 6 same fields - and wanted to know that instead of repeating those columns i could just include a `foreign key` of my timestamp table.

Here is my over simplified example:

**Users table:**

```
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
| ID | timestamp | username              |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
| 1  | 1         | Nobody@nowhere.com    |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
| 2  | 2         | nobody@nothere.ca     |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
| 3  | 3         | nobody@hiding.org     |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
| 4  | 4         | someone@somewhere.com |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
| 5  | 4         | somebody@here.org     |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
```

**Orders table**

```
+----+-----------+--------------------+--------+
| ID | timestamp | ordersBlob         | userid |
+----+-----------+--------------------+--------+
| 1  | 6         | some text          | 1      |
+----+-----------+--------------------+--------+
| 2  | 7         | more text          | 1      |
+----+-----------+--------------------+--------+
| 3  | 8         | no text            | 2      |
+----+-----------+--------------------+--------+
| 4  | 9         | irony poining text | 3      |
+----+-----------+--------------------+--------+
| 5  | 10        | paradox text       | 4      |
+----+-----------+--------------------+--------+
```

**Timestamp table**

```
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| ID | createdOn | createdBy | modifiedOn | modifiedBy |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 20170616  | 1         |            |            |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 2  | 20170621  | 3         | 20170621   | 2          |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 3  | 20160512  | 4         |            |            |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 4  | 20160512  | 4         | 20160516   | 3          |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 5  | 20160101  | 2         |            |            |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 6  | 20160102  | 2         | 20160103   | 3          |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 7  | 20160103  | 4         |            |            |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 8  | 20160104  | 1         |            |            |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 9  | 20160105  | 5         |            |            |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 10 | 20160106  | 1         | 20160106   | 1          |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

These table only serves as an example. would that be ok to do something like that. If you can provide counter-examples and reasons why you would not do it like that, please provide.

*Hope this is not to much opinion based.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not save you any disk space, because 'timestamps' table would require indexes. Also, in realistic scenarios each row in audited tables would require separate row in 'timestamps' table, so 'timestamps' records are very unlikely to be reused.

It will degrade performance of insert/update/selects, as each operation would require touching 2 tables, which would double amount of disk IO (would be even worse, if you want to reuse 'timestamps' records).

In addition, it will make your data tables harder to manage, harder to keep consistent, and your code will become more complicated.

Comment: I did not thought it would slow my operation. Good to keep in mind! Thanks